# R, knitr, and source function: How to preserve source file comments for html report

Tags: r, knitr

**R console:** When I call `source("file_of_functions.R",echo=TRUE)`, all source file expressions, including comments, print to console.

**Knit HTML:** When I put `source("file_of_functions.R",echo=TRUE)` within a chunk and knit to html, the same output prints except for comments.

For clarity of my code and report, I would like the comments of the source file to be included in the html report.

Any suggestions?

**Basic example:** Save the following as f.R:

```
# function to add a number to itself
f <- function(x) x+x
f(2)
```

In console, the call `source("f.R",echo=TRUE)` prints:

> ```
> #function to add a number to itself
> > f <- function(x) x+x
> > f(2)
> > [1] 4
> ```

When knitting to html, the call

````
```{r}
source("f.R",echo=TRUE)
```
````

yields the same output but without the comment.

Comment: `source(..., keep.source = TRUE`) work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

test.Rmd

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
options(prompt = '> ')
```

```{r}
source('./test.r', echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
source('./test.r', echo = TRUE, keep.source = TRUE)
```
````

[image]

Comment: This answer worked well.  For the sake of others with the same question, please also note @Yihui's elegant solution below.

Answer (score 11):

I don't mean to post this as an answer, but I just want to point out the possibility that you can easily insert `test.r` into a code chunk using

````
```{r code=readLines('test.r')}
```
````

Personally I think this is much nicer than using `source()`, e.g. you don't get the prompts `>` by default (you can if you want), and the R code will be syntax highlighted. Of course, your comments will be preserved.

Comment: This is ultra-useful. Two questions: (1) Is it still your recommended way to do that? (2) Perhaps it should feature in the official knitr docs? (Maybe it does.)

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Please feel free to propose any changes to the docs by clicking the edit button (on any of my web pages): https://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Comment: As of 2020-03-12, it seems that you have to add the `eval = FALSE` flag if you do not want to evaluate the code. Maybe this behavior was already in the previous versions of knitr....

Comment: @Mikko It has always been this behavior (because `eval = TRUE` is the default).