# Print external script in Rmarkdown without running it

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In my Rmarkdown document I want to print the code from an external script but not have the code run. Something like source("script.R") but without actually running the code. Below is a hypothetical example, script.R has my code that I want to display but not run.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


You can see the R code below:

```{r}
# I want to print the code from this script but not run it
xxx("script.R")
```
````

Comment: Maybe something with readlines?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149875/r-knitr-and-source-function-how-to-preserve-source-file-comments-for-html-rep)